# Creating a scoring algorithm for voting app

Tags: functions, algorithms, scoring-algorithm

I have just created what I thought to be a good scoring algorithm until I looked at some demo results. It now looks pretty floored though

I have a table with a number of images
I have another table with any number votes on all of the image that have been submitted.

Now rather than just increment a vote counter to output the score, I though I'd do something else so came up with this.

```
  TIME NOW - IMAGE SUBMITTED TIME
( ------------------------------- ) x 1000000 = Score
    TOTAL VOTES FOR THIS IMAGE
```

But the score seems very floored with the images that were recently submitted.

**Example**

*Recent image:* 13 votes, submitted 8528 seconds ago: Scores 1514

*Older image:* 222 votes, submitted 1948015 seconds ago: Scores 110

Is there a better way for me to do this that evens it all out?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use an exponential:

```
Score = (votes from today) + 0.99*(score from yesterday)
```

Comment: So continuing that for each day that has passed since the submission data?

Score = (today) + (0.99 x (today-1) ) + (0.96 x (today-1) ) + ( 0.93 x (today-3) )

Comment: you have many ways to compute an exponential. I think you should update it once a day, so you can use it very fast on every request